# Laravel 9 Livewire Pagination is not working at all

Tags: pagination, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

In my project(s) I want to make use of Livewire Pagination. I have setup everything according to the Livewire Docs. I make use of components to view everything.

I tried the same as you can find in the following code in my real projects, but nothing works.

Here is my code of a test setup (and also here nothing works):

**Model User**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Casts\UserRoleCast;
use App\Constants\UserRole;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
    use WithPagination;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [ ....etc.....
```

**UserPagination.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class UserPagination extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user-pagination', [
            'users' => User::paginate(5)
        ])->layout('layouts.guest');
    }
}
```

**Blade view**

```php
<div>
    <table class="table min-w-full mb-4">
        <thead>
            <tr class="border-b-2 border-gray-300">
                <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-sm leading-4 tracking-wider">ID</th>
                <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-sm leading-4 tracking-wider">Naam</th>
                <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-sm leading-4 tracking-wider">Email</th>
                <th class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-sm leading-4 tracking-wider">Password</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @forelse($users as $user)
{{-- <tr class="border-b border-gray-500" wire:key="user-{{ $user->id }}"> --}}
            <tr class="border-b border-gray-500">
                <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-sm leading-5">
                    {{ $user->id }}
                </td>
                <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-sm leading-5">
                    {{ $user->name }}
                </td>
                <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-sm leading-5">
                    {{ $user->email }}
                </td>
                <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-sm leading-5">
                    {{ $user->password }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            @empty
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-sm leading-5">Geen sponsors gevonden</td>
            </tr>
            @endforelse
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ $users->links() }}
</div>
```

**composer.json**

```json
  "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.13",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",
```

**Furthermore**
I have my @livewireStyles and my @livewireScripts at the right place. I know it's right, because the rest of the application is working.

But clicking on the links doesn't do anything. Nothing changes in de URI and nothing happens on screen.

What is wrong here? Why doesn't it working?

I tried everything according to the Livewire Docs and 'solutions' I found online.

Comment: I have done some research and dove into the code of Livewire en Laravel. I noticed that all the methods are triggered but that at the end the page is not rerendered. Strange thing is when I adjust the URI to go to page 2 en press enter the page shows the right data and then de button to go to page 1 works once. After returning to page 1 the rest of the buttons again don't work. There is no way the page rerenders after clicking a button in the paginator links.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I made a mistake by adding a use statement in the models, the use statement:

```php
use WithPaginator
```

This is a Livewire trait and only for livewire components.
I removed the use statement and everything worked.

Another problem is when I load for example all Users with pagination in the mount method of a component I get an error. Solution here was to load all Users in de render method.

Comment: Another problem could be giving a return type of View to the render method of the component. I will test this.